# Ipod Touch 3G vs Iphone for app development

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPod touch for iPhone development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134048/ipod-touch-for-iphone-development)

Is the new Ipod Touch 3G support all the apps designed for iPhone? and how does the 32GB version of iPod Touch stack up against the iPhone 3GS hardware-wise (as in CPU/memory) ?

Can i develop apps seamlessly on the iPod Touch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ipod touch is missing some features of the iphone.

- You don't have the phone,
- You only have wifi network (no 3G
  network)
- No Camera
- No GPS
- and some other matters (like
  accelerometer and compass)

You can start with ipod touch, and unless your app is using any of the above then you should be ok. But make sure you plan your app and see if it will require any features that might not be on the ipod touch

we are using ipod touch but also testing on iphone (mostly for no-wifi scenarios)

Comment: Note that even though the Touch has no GPS, you can use CoreLocation - it uses WiFi triangulation.  Also, you can use the image picker with the photo library to simulate taking images, and the Touch DOES have an accelerometer (but no compass)

Comment: @Kendall thank you for the clarification about the accelerometer