# Is it possible to develop apps for iOS with iPod?

Tags: ios

I develop games for Android, but now I want to try the iOS platform. Actually, I have Mac Mini, but I haven't enought money to buy iPhone, so I think about buying iPod Touch instead. Is it possible to develop games (Unity engine) using iPod? What about games performance? Sorry if I ask something stupid, I never developed for iOS before, thanks!

Comment: same code will work in iphone,ipad ,ipod .so no problem.so that the name of IDE is xcode

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134048/ipod-touch-for-iphone-development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use an iTouch for development (cheaper than buying iPad2's). So yes, you can definitely develop for iOS using an iTouch/iPod.

You will also need to join the Apple developer program before you can deploy to the iTouch - Apple has a $99 annual fee for an individual. Even if you purchase Unity you will need buy into the Apple dev program too.

Answer (score 1):

same code will work in iphone,ipad ,ipod .so no problem.so that the name of IDE is xcode.but performance and image accuracy will be varied.

http://unity3d.com/company/news/iphone-press.html

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides a SDK including a simulator. Never trust the simulator completely, but you can use it easily for day by day job, and test it on a real iphone, ipod touch or similar only from time to time.