# How to test on the IPhone without having access to one?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

Want to write a site for the iphone, but I don't have one and I don't know anyone who has one.

Is there a way to develop for it without having access to one, maybe apple has some sort of sim for this or something.

Anyone know of anything?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121018/is-it-possible-to-develop-for-the-iphone-without-an-iphone

Answer (score 3):

An iPhone simulator is included with the iPhone SDK, which can be downloaded for free from here:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/start/register/

Or, if you have the Safari web browser, you can use this for a fairly accurate result:
http://www.testiphone.com/ or http://iphonetester.com/

Comment: You need to be using the Safari web browser. Here is another site: http://iphonetester.com/

Comment: Those web-based iPhone simulators are massive gimmicks.

Comment: I was using Safari. It still didn't work Without the zoom, you don't get a feel for how it'll look.

Comment: Yes, you're not going to be able to get a totally accurate representation unless you download the SDK and use the simulator.

Comment: From all of my testing with the iPhone, nothing comes close to actually testing on the device.

Comment: LOL @ pronunciation of "testiphone"

Comment: Looks like you can't download the SDK for free anymore. There's no download links on that apple page above, and it appears you need to enrol $99 a year. Thanks for making it difficult to build your shit apple.

Answer (score 1):

There's a iPhone simulator for Aptana (should work on any system) and an emulator Apple provides (if you have a Mac). I've not tested the Aptana one. The Apple one is pretty good, but it runs most web stuff much faster than the actual device.

Answer (score 0):

Try buying an iPod Touch.  It has most of what you need to test your code to make sure it's iPhone ready.

The simulator is available for convenience but you won't be able to check proper HIG such as buttons or text being too small.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick test, try regular Safari zoomed until the dimensions of viewport are similar to those of iPhone. Safari exists for Windows too :) Moreover, you can ask it to present itself as iPhone (in the Develop menu) and try a couple of sites.

For a serious development you definitely need iPod Touch. You'll need to have a familiarity with how interface, both native and mobile web, works. The SDK won't be able to give you that.

I wonder though what kind of application you are developing. I don't think web-based applications are that useful or bring revenue at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest running VM ware booting up Mac OS...

You'll need an intel CPU though but still, worth it.

See here:
[How to load Mac OS Lion in a VM](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2011/09/how-to-install-fully-functional-mac-os-x-lion-virtual-machine-inside-windows-7/)