# emulating iPad, iPhone on Windows

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, ipad, emulation

Is there any emulator for doing this? I want to create some checks of how an HTML5 app is displayed on this devices but I don't have any.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test on the IPhone without having access to one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928955/how-to-test-on-the-iphone-without-having-access-to-one)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to develop for the iPhone without an iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121018/is-it-possible-to-develop-for-the-iphone-without-an-iphone)

Comment: @MattBall I love how the question you proposed as a duplicate is really a duplicate of another question ...

Comment: @Foo that was deliberate. More duplicate question links for the price of one

Comment: @MattBall begs the philosophical question: is the duplicate of a duplicate also a duplicate of the original question ...

Comment: Is this for testing a web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official iOS simulator is only available for OSX

Answer (score 0):

Apple licenses doesn't allow you to use their software on a non-Apple machine. So you should get a Mac laptop/computer or ask someone to borrow it for some time.